# SwiftUI .openURL return a wrong URL when have underscore at last

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to allow user click to a URL inside a `Text` view and open that URL but got issue for some kind of URLs as below.

`.openURL` is missing underscore (`_`) at last character.

###### Reproduce code

```
Text("Test url click https://example.com/aaa_")
    .environment(\.openURL, OpenURLAction { url in
        print(url)
    
        return .handled
    })
    .tint(.blue)
```

###### Result:

[image]

```
https://example.com/aaa
```

###### Expected:

```
https://example.com/aaa_
```

Any help!

Comment: Is the URL something dynamic that you need to detect, or is it hardcoded? If it is hardcoded, you can just write some markdown to ensure it is always a link.

Comment: Testing URL above is hard code, in real project, user can input URL and addition text wrapping URL such "some text https://.... some text". This app same to Facebook that user can paste URL into comment message, so markdown seems not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting things like this are always going to produce false positives and/or false negatives. You can't read the users' minds and figure out which parts of their input is *meant* to be a URL.

For this particular case, [`NSDataDetector`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector) can successfully find the correct portion of the string that is meant to be a URL. You can write a function that converts a `String` to an `AttributedString` with the `link` attribute applied to the detected URLs' ranges.

```
func detectLinks(_ string: String) -> AttributedString {
    var result = AttributedString(string)
    guard let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType.link.rawValue) else {
        return result
    }
    
    let matches = detector.matches(in: string, range: NSRange(location: 0, length: string.utf16.count))
    
    for match in matches {
        guard let range = Range(match.range, in: string),
              let lowerBound = AttributedString.Index(range.lowerBound, within: result),
              let upperBound = AttributedString.Index(range.upperBound, within: result) else { continue }
        let url = String(string[range])
        result[lowerBound..<upperBound].link = URL(string: url)
    }
    return result
}
```

Usage:

```
Text(detectLinks("Test url click https://example.com/aaa_"))
```

That said, there might be cases where `NSDataDetector` fails to detect URLs correctly, but SwiftUI's `Text` succeeds.